# MIN_HEAPIFY algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Is the following MIN_HEAPIFY algorithm correct?

```
MIN_HEAPIFY(A,i)
{
l=LEFT(i);//calculates the left childs location
r=RIGHT(i);//right childs location

if((l<=A.heap_size)AND(A[l]<A[i]))
   small=l;
else
   small=i;

if((r<=A.heapsize)&&(A[small]>A[r]))
   small=r;

if(small!=i)
  {
   exchange A[i] with A[small];
   MIN_HEAPIFY(A,i)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not correct,

```
if(small!=i)
  {
   exchange A[i] with A[small];
   MIN_HEAPIFY(A,i)
  }
```

you only heapify more when `A[i]` is larger than one of its direct children. And you recur with the same index, which means the second call will do nothing.

I've explained a correct version of `heapify` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14903012/1011995).

Comment: But I donot want MAX-HEAP algorithm I want MiN_HEAPIFY only

Comment: No difference in principle, just switch the comparisons for the heap elements, `<` becomes `>` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Java implementation. Hope it helps.

```
/**
 * Down-top heapify
 * @param index
 */
private void heapUp(int index){
    if(index > 1){
        int parent = index / 2;
        if(comp.compare(data[parent],data[index]) > 0 ){    
            swap(parent, index);
            heapUp(parent);
        }
    }
}
/**
 * Top-Down heapify
 * @param index
 */
private void heapDown(int index){
    int left = index * 2;
    int right = index *2 + 1;
    if( right >= size+1 && left >= size+1 ){ 
        data[size+1] = null;
        return;
    }

    int small = comp.compare(data[right],data[left]) >= 0 ? left : right;
    if(comp.compare(data[index],data[small]) >= 0){
        swap(small, index);
        heapDown(small);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just replace `MIN_HEAPIFY(A,i)` with `MIN_HEAPIFY(A,small)` because now you need to go to the respective child of the node which is larger than `A[i]`, since that index is small now, recur with small.